# How can I detect value syntax errors in app.config files?

Tags: c#, .net, settings, app-config, system.configuration

I need to improve the reporting of errors in app.config files.

I have a tiny test app that includes a setting of type "int".  If I change its value in app.config to something that isn't a valid integer, I'd expect an exception to get raised that I can catch and report.  Unfortunately, something is eating the exception.  Is there a straightforward way to prevent that behaviour and let the exception propagate out?

My Settings.Designer.cs file (generated by Visual Studio):

```
[global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute(
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "10.0.0.0")]
internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {

    private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

    public static Settings Default { get { return defaultInstance; } }

    [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("17")]
    public int SecondSetting
    {
        get { return ((int)(this["SecondSetting"])); }
        set { this["SecondSetting"] = value; }
    }
}
```

My C# test app:

```
static void Main (string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(AppConfigTests.Properties.Settings.Default.SecondSetting);
    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
    }
}
```

The relevant portion of my App.config file (note that the value isn't a valid integer):

```
<userSettings>
    <AppConfigTests.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="SecondSetting" serializeAs="String">
            <value>1foo7</value>
        </setting>
    </AppConfigTests.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
```

A System.Format exception is getting thrown by System.Number.StringToNumber, but something is catching it and throwing it away, and my catch block never gets entered.  In the Visual Studio debugger output, I found "A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll", but that doesn't help me except to further confirm that an exception was thrown.

I tried adding an IntegerValidatorAttribute to my setting property in Settings.Designer.cs, but that didn't help (and I made sure the .cs didn't get regenerated).

I tried adding the following code at the top of my main() method, but that didn't help either:

```
foreach (SettingsProperty sp in AppConfigTests.Properties.Settings.Default.Properties)
    sp.ThrowOnErrorDeserializing = true;
```

I've thought of implementing my own ConfigurationSection, but I'm hoping there's an easier solution.

Just to reiterate: I need a way to report errors in settings values in app.config files.

(If I break the XML syntax in App.config (by removing an angle bracket, for example), my catch block gets a nice exception with all the detail I could ask for.)

Comment: I'm curious about what you did for this, as I am having a similar issue...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this (assuming you have all the setting values overriden in app.config):

```
  foreach (SettingsPropertyValue propertyValue in AppConfigTests.Properties.Settings.Default.PropertyValues) {
    if (propertyValue.UsingDefaultValue) {
      throw new Exception(propertyValue.Name + " is not deserialized properly.");
    }
  }
```

If you're writing web application, it is firing this event when deserialization fails:

```
try {
  if (this.IsHostedInAspnet()) {
    object[] args = new object[] { this.Property, this, ex };
    Type type = Type.GetType("System.Web.Management.WebBaseEvent, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", true);
    type.InvokeMember("RaisePropertyDeserializationWebErrorEvent", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, null, args, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  }
}
catch {
}
```

Otherwise, it just get back to default value, so only thing you can to is iterate trough all values and check if they're not defaulted.